# Is it a good style to write constants on the left of equal to == in If statement in C++?

Tags: c++, coding-style

Are there any recommendations about writing constants on the left of comparison [operator equal to ==](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) in [If statement in C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)) to avoid bug if assignment will be mistyped. Is it a good practice ? or this will reduce code readability and not recommended to do that, as there is a [Compiler Warning (level 4) C4706](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hw7c1he.aspx) in case if assignment within conditional expression will be written.

```
const int maxValue = 15;
```

1)

```
if (currentValue == maxValue)
{
    // do something 
}
```

(

***if  operator equal to == will mistyped to assignment operator =, currentValue = maxValue the if will be always true as anything that isn’t zero is “true”***

Or better to write

2)

```
if (maxValue == currentValue)
{
   // do something 
}
```